# axis scale shift in d3.js

Tags: animation, d3.js

I am fairly new to d3.js

I am looking for a way to animate both x and y axises based on the new data. So it is more of a real time animation where the x axis is moving and the new data pops out from the right and y axis get updated dynamically as well and after a while the old data dissapear because I have so many data points.

I have this chart already made. https://jsfiddle.net/elvalencian/mfLjovx9/4/

```
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3
  .select("#root")
  .append("svg")
  .attr(
    "viewBox",
    `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${
    height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sultanmalki/d3js/main/saudi_fdi.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d) {
    return {
      date: d3.timeParse("%Y")(d.date),
      value: d.value
    }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }))
      .range([0, width]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .transition().duration(5000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return +d.value;
      })])
      .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(5000)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


    // Add the line
    const linePath = svg
      .append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#00B0F1")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal)
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date)
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.value)
        })
      )

    const pathLength = linePath.node().getTotalLength();
    linePath
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", pathLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", pathLength)
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + ")")
      .duration(5000)
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

  })
```

I would really appreciate any help.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Lines are rather difficult to animate, since they are only one `path` object instead of multiple objects as e. g. in a bar or scatter plot. You are already using the `stroke-dasharray` attribute for the animation of the static data. When there is new data, you need to

1. Rescale the axes:

To achieve this, compute the domain for `x` and `y` and set it via the `domain` method. Then re-render the axes with `call(AxisObject)` using a `transition`. Use the same transition `t` for both `x` and `y`.

2. Rescale the existing line

With the rescaled axes, also the existing line path must be rescaled. This works smoothly by transitioning the `d` attribute using the transition `t` before binding the new data.

3. Add new data

Wait till the end of transition `t` to bind the new data to the line path. Before doing that, calculate `getTotalLength` in order to set `stroke-dasharray` such that the new data is initially hidden. Then transition `stroke-dasharray` to the new path length. As the second value for `stroke-dasharray` I used `9999` which must be chosen longer than the maximal expected path length of the new data.

```js
// Some stuff to generate random time series
// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn() {
    let u = 0, v = 0;
  while (u === 0) u = Math.random();
  while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
  return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
}
// Simulate geometric brownian motion
const mu = 0.8;
const sigma = 0.5;
function simulate() {
    const prev = data[data.length - 1];
  const x = prev.x + 0.01;
  const bm = prev.bm + Math.sqrt(0.01) * randn();
    data.push({
    x: x,
    bm: bm,
    y: Math.exp((mu - sigma * sigma / 2) * x + sigma * bm)
  });
}
// Initial data
let data = [{
  x: 0,
  bm: 0,
  y: 1,
}];
// Add data to chart in chunks
const blockSize = 20;
let blockCounter = 0;
function addData() {
  simulate();
  blockCounter += 1;
  if (blockCounter === blockSize) {
    render(data.slice());
    blockCounter = 0;
  }
}
// Chart definitions
const width = 500,
            height = 180,
      marginLeft = 30,
      marginRight = 10,
      marginBottom = 30,
      marginTop = 10;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const xSlidingWindow = 2;

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(3);

const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.x))
  .y(d => y(d.y));

const gx = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`);

const gy = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`);

// Clip path to only show lines inside the axes
const clipPath = svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-rect")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", marginLeft)
    .attr("y", marginTop)
    .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
    .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom);

const path = svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.slice())
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-rect)")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0, 9999");

function render(arr) {
    // compute domain
  const xMax = d3.max(arr, d => d.x);
  x.domain([Math.max(xMax - xSlidingWindow, 0), Math.max(xSlidingWindow, xMax)]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(arr, d => d.y));
  // First, transition the axes
  const t = d3.transition().duration(interval * blockSize / 2);
  gx.transition(t).call(xAxis);
  gy.transition(t).call(yAxis);
  path.transition(t).attr("d", line);
  t.on("end", () => {
    // Then add new data
    let pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path.datum(arr)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", `${pathLength}, 9999`)
      .attr("d", line);
    pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path.transition().duration(interval * blockSize / 2)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", `${pathLength}, 9999`)
      .attr("d", line);
  });
}

// Interval for data simulation
let intervalId;
const interval = 50;
function startStream() {
    if (!intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(addData, interval);
   }
}
function stopStream() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = null;
}
function reset() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  data = [{
    x: 0,
    bm: 0,
    y: 1,
  }];
  intervalId = setInterval(addData, interval);
}
d3.select("#start").on("click", startStream);
d3.select("#stop").on("click", stopStream);
d3.select("#reset").on("click", reset);
render(data.slice());
startStream();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<svg></svg>
```